# Making internet radio app

Tags: iphone, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I'm making my own internet radio app with a custom interface. So i'm wondering what is the best tool to implement the audio playback with a custom interface? I tried to use MPMoviePlayerController, but i couldn't find out how to customize it's interface. I also tried AVPlayer, but somehow it didn't play the .m3u files, though it worked perfectly well with .m3u8 playlists from apple test http live stream examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use audiostreamer its also having a good example https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

cheers endo